# How to bind url parameters to controller argument object in jax-rs

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller, jax-rs

I must inject Spring *Pageable* object to *@GET* annotated handler, when user queries */rest/data?page=1&limit=20* populated with the parameters according to this guide

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html

```
@GET
@Path("/rest/data")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF8"})
public List<SanomalokiDTO> getData(Pageable pageable) {
    return service.getData(pageable);
}
```

However, I get the following error

```
SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class org.springframework.data
.domain.Pageable, ContentType: application/octet-stream
elo 19, 2016 12:06:24 IP. org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMappe
r toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.
java:1315)
...
```

I tried to add `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})` annotation to handler but still get the same error. It seems like jax-rs  is trying to build the object from empty message body rather than the url parameters. How do I bind the pageable object to those parameters and inject it without having to inject *@RequestParam*'s and build it manually?

Answer (score 2):

You have to annotate the pagable argument with [BeanParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) annotation. And then inside the Pageable you have to annotate your fields with [QueryParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html)

So something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/rest/data")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF8"})
public List<SanomalokiDTO> getData(@BeanParam Pageable pageable) {
    return service.getData(pageable);
}
```

And your Pageable class:

```
public class Pageable {
    @QueryParam("page")
    private Integer page;
    @QueryParam("limit")
    private Integer limit;
    ...
}
```

In case you don't have a control over Pageable class you can work it around as follow:

```
public class PageableBuilder {
    @QueryParam("page")
    private Integer page;
    @QueryParam("limit")
    private Integer limit;
    ...

    public Pageable build() {
        //create Pageable object
    }
}
```

And in the resource:

```
@GET
@Path("/rest/data")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF8"})
public List<SanomalokiDTO> getData(@BeanParam PageableBuilder pageableBuilder) {
    return service.getData(pageableBuilder.create());
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way around? Pageable is provided by Spring, and only choice would be to implement this class myself

Answer (score 0):

You could map your query params using `@BeanParam` feature and construct your `PageRequest` manually (remember that pageNumber is zero-indexed).

```
@GET
@Path("/rest/data")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=UTF8"})
public List<SanomalokiDTO> getData(@BeanParam MyPageRequest myPageRequest) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(myPageRequest.page, myPageRequest.limit);
    return service.getData(pageRequest);
}
```

and

```
class MyPageRequest {

    @QueryParam("page")
    public int page;

    @QueryParam("limit")
    public int limit;
}
```